# What's the difference between 'attaining awareness' and 'understanding of sensory information'?

Tags: differences, terminology

the word 'perception' has two meaning in wikipedia:

> perception is the process of **attaining awareness** or **understanding of sensory information**

example 1:

> With microphones, cameras, accelerometers, compasses, temperature gauges, and brightness detectors, smartphones have become extra-sensory devices, able to augment your own **perceptions**.

example 2:

> cannot perceive it, out of **perception**.

I think the example 1 take the first meaning and example 2 take the second. why i need to make this difference ? Because my teacher told me that Human perception is limited by the capacity of sense organs. which means we **cannot augment perception**. And yes, we human being can employ the man-made sensors, but actually it's the man-made sensors perceive the world, not us. they just told us the results, we didn't perceive it, we just know it.

so, I want to know the actually meaning of 'perception'. if perception only means get information **from 5** normal sensors of human. then the example 1 is wrong!

Comment: Well, there's nothing to say that example 1 _can't_ be wrong. If you limit 'perception' only to that which your senses (of which there are quite a few more than 5) sense, then, yes, it could well be wrong.

Comment: What' your definition for the word **perception** ? This is what I want to know, because I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Didn't you already ask that earlier today in another question?

Comment: [About the word "perception"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10706/about-the-word-perception) really asks about the differences between three words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description for *perception* given from the NOAD is:

> the ability to see, hear, or become aware of something through the senses: *the normal limits to human perception*.
>     • the state of being or process of becoming aware of something in such a way: *the perception of pain*.
>     • a way of regarding, understanding, or interpreting something; a mental impression: *Hollywood's perception of the tastes of the American public* | *we need to challenge many popular perceptions of old age*.
>     • intuitive understanding and insight: *“He wouldn't have accepted,” said my mother with unusual perception*.

The first example sentence says that such devices increase the perception we have through our senses, in the same way a telescope increase our sensorial perceptions; for example, the cellular phone increases (in a figurative way), what we can hear, as it allows to hear people who is far from us.

In the second example, *perception* is used to mean *a way of regarding, understanding, or interpreting something*, or *mental impression*.